# Remove the last element in ul based on certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a `ul` list with a lot of `li` inside it, moreover I've an input type hidden under few `li`.

I want to remove or set display none dynamically to those `li` which is does not have any hidden `input` next to itself.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my snippet :

```js
$('#q li:last-child').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="q">
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">2</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you want an answer only in jQuery, you should probably remove the javascript tag

Comment: @Anthony i removed the jquery term in my question instead

Comment: the HTML is wrongly generated, don't mix LI with INPUT in the same level of the UL, I recommended you to insert input in LI and it will be cleaner and better to manipulate JS with this.

Comment: You cannot had `input` inside `ul`, it has to be inside `li`.

Comment: Agreed with @ZiTAL  and Milan

Comment: @inaz your mark up is wrong and there is no need for loop here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can iterate over the `li` and check if there is an input next to it, if not then hide it. something like this:

```js
$('#q li').each(function(){
if(!$(this).next('input').length)
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="q">
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">2</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you used jquery 1.11.1  and that not working.BTW i changed it and it's working now

Comment: it is working, i copied the snippet from question, op has used it.

Comment: It's ok then but when i run your snippet previously (before my edit) , it says `$ not defined`. It's ok now

Comment: @Dij Thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

You should not use input tags within ul. HTML formation is not correct!

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
setTimeout(()=>{
    a = $("#q").find("li").last().remove();
   $("#output").html(a)
}, 2000)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="q">
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">2</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">3</a></li>
</ul>
Removed element <div id="output"> - </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS solution.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('q').children

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].tagName === 'LI') {
    if (list[i+1] === undefined || list[i+1].tagName !== 'INPUT') {
      list[i].style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="q">
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">2</a></li>
  <input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">3</a></li>
  <input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">4</a></li>
  <input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">5</a></li>
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark up is wrong. LI is only child of UL
2. Place input inside li.
3. Then use [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```js
$('#q li:not(:has(input))').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="q">
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">1</a>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
  </li>
  
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">2</a>
  
  <input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
  </li>
  
  <li><a class="PageNumber" data-href="home.htm">3</a></li>
</ul>
```